# Is it ok to use less than 10 pieces for bedikas chametz

Tags: bedikas-chametz

i have always hid 10 pieces of chametz for bedikas chametz. Are there other minhagim other than 10 pieces?

Comment: Some people have the minhag to put a piece in each room that requires *bedikah* and the exact number does not matter. 10 is from the Ari Z"L but is not required. It is however, easier to verify that they were all picked up if you have an exact number.